# Adding Tkinter Entry into SQLite Database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am currently having trouble trying to make my SQLite database update its records using values entered by the user in my `tkinter` entry boxes. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
root = Tk()

root.title("Player Statistics DBMS")
root.geometry('700x400')
root.config(bg="light blue")



conn = sqlite3.connect('player_stats.db')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player_stats ( 
        first_name text,
        points integer, 
        assists integer, 
        rebounds integer, 
        shots_made integer,
        shots_missed integer)""")

cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()


first_name = StringVar()
points = IntVar()
assists = IntVar()
rebounds = IntVar()
shots_made = IntVar()
shots_missed = IntVar()
status = StringVar()




player_name = Label(top, text='Player First Name:')
player_name.place(x=290, y=20)
player_name = Entry(top, width=10)
player_name.place(x=300, y=50)

points_label = Label(top, text="Number of Points:")
points_label.place(x=37, y=100)
entry_points = Entry(top, width=10)
entry_points.place(x=45, y=130)

assist_label = Label(top, text="Number of Assists:")
assist_label.place(x=192, y=100)
assist_label = Entry(top, width=10)
assist_label.place(x=207, y=130)

rebound_label = Label(top, text="Number of Rebounds:")
rebound_label.place(x=350, y=100)
rebound_label = Entry(top, width=10)
rebound_label.place(x=369, y=130)

turnovers_label = Label(top, text="Number of Turnovers:")
turnovers_label.place(x=520, y=100)
turnovers_label = Entry(top, width=10)
turnovers_label.place(x=541, y=130)

shots_made_label = Label(top, text="Number of Shots Made:")
shots_made_label.place(x=106, y=200)
shots_made_label = Entry(top, width=10
shots_made_label.place(x=129, y=230)

shots_missed_label = Label(top, text="Number of Shots Missed:")
shots_missed_label.place(x=440, y=200)
shots_missed_label = Entry(top, width=10)
shots_missed_label.place(x=465, y=230)

enter_data_button = Button(top, text="Enter")
enter_data_button.place(x=336, y=280)

def get():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('player_stats.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into player_stats values('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')") \
    %(first_name.get(), points.get(), assists.get(), rebounds.get(), shots_made.get(), shots_missed.get())
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print(conn.fetchall())
    print(status.set("Data Entered Successfully"))


enter_data_button = Button(top, text="Enter", command=get)
enter_data_button.place(x=336, y=280)
```

So the idea is that whenever the user inputs into the GUI and clicks the enter button, the function `get()` will run and the code will collect the data inputted by the user, and the database will update. When this is complete, the code will output `Data Entered Succesfully`. However when I run this I get an error.
This was my error trace:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'sqlite3.Cursor' and 'tuple'
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and place the full error trace in your question. If you do not understand what error trace mean, please use Google and read other Python questions. You also need to add the **python** tag.

Comment: There is extra `)`  before \.

Comment: Hi, I believe this was the error trace. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'sqlite3.Cursor' and 'tuple'

Comment: Use this: cur.execute(first_name.get(), points.get(), assists.get(), rebounds.get(), shots_made.get(), shots_missed.get()) \
    %("insert into player_stats values('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')")

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I run what you have suggested, I get a new error: TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (6 given) 

Do you know what this means? Something to do with my function "get"?

Answer (score 0):

The `)` before the `\` in the following line:

```py
cur.execute("insert into player_stats values('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')") \
    %(first_name.get(), points.get(), assists.get(), rebounds.get(), shots_made.get(), shots_missed.get())
```

should be moved to the end of the statement like below:

```py
cur.execute("insert into player_stats values('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" \
    %(first_name.get(), points.get(), assists.get(), rebounds.get(), shots_made.get(), shots_missed.get()))
```

However using string substitution may risk SQL injection, it is better to use *placeholders* instead:

```py
cur.execute("insert into player_stats values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    (first_name.get(), points.get(), assists.get(), rebounds.get(), shots_made.get(), shots_missed.get()))
```